# debugging ios push kit with profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, sdk, apple-push-notifications

I am using ios push kit in an ios app. Everything is working fine, but now and then receiving push on the device fails. 
If I restart the device everything works fine.

In the log file I get the error "Failed sending message to client". 
Now I installed the profile given here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG24

Although everything is working fine now (because of the restart), I wonder if these warnings could be relevant to shoot down the error. 
Under working conditions I get:

```
<Warning>: LaunchServices: no bundle found with identifier com.apple.apsd

apsd[81] <Error>: WiFi:[464088265.053899]: WiFiManagerClientDispatchAttachmentEvent: attached en0

apsd[81] <Notice>: 2015-09-16 11:24:28 +0200 apsd[81]: Unable to bootstrap_lookup connection port for 'com.apple.telephonyutilities.callservicesdaemon.voip.push.development': Unknown service name

<Notice>: 2015-09-16 11:24:33 +0200 apsd[81]: Unknown environment 'demo'

apsd[81] <Warning>: [Warning] Services all disappeared, removing all dependent devices

---
```

EDIT: 
Found this interesting link:

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/257354?start=50&tstart=0

Since nobody answered, I continued in a new thread here:

[Apple Push - didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload not called - instead error: Failed sending message to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694731/apple-push-didreceiveincomingpushwithpayload-not-called-instead-error-faile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find a solution to this problem. 
I decided to use standard APNS for pushes instead.